# Filter pack scale on Unicolor enlarger

Tags: filters, darkroom, enlarging

[image: pic of Unicolor enlarger head]I'm trying to get back into color printing and came across this Unicolor enlarger in a junk pile, the filter dials only go up to 17. Is that the actual value of the filter or this this a unique scale system to Unicolor? From what I remember the starting point was usually 20 or 40 on magenta and yellow 17 would seem pretty useless for most color printing.

For some reason the picture I put of the enlarger didn't upload in the original post. The dials only go from 0-17 with 4 spaces between each number and there doesn't seem to be a decimal as suggested in the answer bellow. Im use to seeing filter packs ranging from 0-170 or 0-200 does this enlarger only go up to 17 or is it scaled to something else and if so how does it translate to the usual values of 0-200 ect.? I wasn't able to find much info online about this enlarger

Answer (score 4):

I think you are omitting the decimal point. I think the max setting is 1.70. The starting filter pack is a variable based on the red, green, and blue emulsion speeds. That being said: The average setting is 0.00 cyan 0.50 magenta  0.80 Yellow.

Higher cyan adds red. Lower cyan add cyan. Higher magenta adds green. Lower magenta adds magenta. Higher yellow adds blue. Lower yellow adds yellows.

0.05 = 1/6 f-stop   0.10 = 1/3 f-stop  0.15 = 1/2 f-stop 0.20 = 2/3 f-stop 0.30 = 1 f-stop 0.60 = 2 f-stops 0.90 = 3 f-stops 1.20 = 4 f-stops 1.50 = 5 f-stop 1.80 = 6 f-stops of attenuation.

It is commonplace to drop the decimal point when working a color enlarger.